# Shopify, make user land directly on checkout page from your website/app

Tags: shopify

When user click on the shopify link from my website (not shopify) I want to add products programmatically on cart and then take the user directly to the payment page.

Means I don't want user to go through a product selection process, I want app to do It all I want user to do is make a payment for the payable amount.

So the question is how to create a cart in your website/webapp and make user directly land on the checkout page in shopify store or what api to use.

thanks and open for suggestions.

Comment: "don't want user to go through a product selection process" = if I want to buy a XL size shirt I must buy a X size?

Comment: @someoneuseless not every store is a clothing store, it could be a single product, one per order, store where adding to the cart adds no value to the user.

Comment: @Ben technicaly speaking what I want to say is that this shop cannot have any variant or only 1 available variant. And it is impossible to anyone want to buy more than 2 kind of product.

Answer (score 0):

It was simple, found it easily after some searching. All I needed was a [checkout API.](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/create-a-checkout-with-storefront-api)